# Не выполняется PHP запрос каждые несколько секунд

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

есть файл not.php и в нем такой запрос (прошу сильно не ругать)

```
<?php 
$query = "select * from notifications where seen = '0'";
$result = mysqli_query($con, $query);

$not_count = 0;

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
    $not_count++;
}

echo "<script>var not_count = $not_count;</script>";
?>
```

На странице index.php подключаю not.php таким образом

```
<div id="div-not">
<?php include("not.php") ?>
</div>
```

и далее в этой же странице точнее на index.php обновляю not.php вот так :

```
setInterval(function()
{
$("#div-not").load ("not.php");
}, 2000);
```

Но почему то при загрузке страницы каждые 3 секунд запрос в базу не выполняется. В чем может быть проблема ? Вопрос ранее не задавался, то что вы показываете дубликатом это совсем другой вопрос

Comment: Если оставить в сторону ужасный способ реализации через постоянные запросы, то почему бы вам не использовать AJAX?

Comment: ужасный не ужасный, нужен ответ на вопрос, если не трудно

Comment: Ну ответ вам уже дали. А вообще лучше конечно использовать веб сокеты для такого.

Comment: Очень интересная реализация) Какие-то ошибки пишутся в консоль браузера?

Comment: YevgeniyM нет никаких ошибок...

Comment: Stepan Kasyanenko, к сожалению в последнее время на русском стековерфлоу ответы только составляют фразы и реплики типа "ужасно, отвратительно и да кто же так делает" а конкретизации нету...спасибо конечно за вебсокеты, но вопрос в другом почему не работает "агрегат" что стоит выше )